# Запретить скролл на странице, но разрешить на моб меню

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня мобильное меню, больше чем высота экрана. Я хочу запретить скролл страницы, но разрешить скролл в меню, тк обычно меню по высоте больше чем окно.

```
$('.menumob').click(function () {
            $('#mobile-menu').fadeIn(400).css({
                display: 'flex'
            });
             $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
        });

        //Close mobile menu
        $('.menumob_close').click(function () {
            $('#mobile-menu').fadeOut(400);
             $("body").css("overflow","auto");
        });
```

Этот код отключает скролл, но так же отключает и в меню. Добавлял `overflow:auto` и `overflow:scroll` не помогло.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это можно решить с помощью  css. Задайте размеры вашего body равные размеру экрана, а все, что выходит за пределы спрячьте - так у вас не будет скролла страницы. А меню поместите в контейнер с вертикальной прокруткой, например так:

```css
body{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.body-container{
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:lightgrey;
}

.mobile-menu{
 width:200px;
 max-height: 100vh;
 overflow-y:scroll;
 border:1px solid black;
}

.mobile-menu .mobile-menu-item{
  height:100px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class = "body-container">
 <div class = "mobile-menu">
   <div class = "mobile-menu-item">Пункт меню</div>
   <div class = "mobile-menu-item">Пункт меню</div>
   <div class = "mobile-menu-item">Пункт меню</div>
   <div class = "mobile-menu-item">Пункт меню</div>
   <div class = "mobile-menu-item">Пункт меню</div>
   <div class = "mobile-menu-item">Пункт меню</div>
   <div class = "mobile-menu-item">Пункт меню</div>
   <div class = "mobile-menu-item">Пункт меню</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогли!